# Creating a matrix of matrices using numpy.array()

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've been trying to create a matrix of matrices using the numpy function numpy.array() and am facing difficulties

I'm specifically trying to create the following matrix

[

[

```
 [                    [
   [ 1 ,2 ]             [ 1 , 2 ]
   [ 3 ,4 ]             [ 3 , 4 ]
 ]               ,    ]
```

]

[

```
 [                    [
   [ 1 ,2 ]             [ 1 , 2 ]
   [ 3 ,4 ]             [ 3 , 4 ]
 ]               ,    ]
```

]

]

more precisely like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPbnO.png)

I've tried the following line in Jupyter

```
x = np.array( [
        [   [ 1,2 ] ,[ 3, 4]  ] ,  [   [ 1,2 ] ,[ 3, 4]  ] ,
        [   [ 1,2 ] ,[ 3, 4]  ] ,  [   [ 1,2 ] ,[ 3, 4]  ]
])
```

but what it does is puts all the  2X2 matrices in row-wise form.

I'm not able to take **2**( 2X2 ) matrices in row form and replicate them in columns or **2** ( 2X2 ) matrices in column form and replicate them into rows

Any idea how to create this using numpy.array() or any other approach( using numpy functions )

it seem simple but I'm finding difficulties in formulating the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.array` replicates the nesting of the input brackets exactly.

Comment: `numpy` does not dIsplay a (2,2,2,2) array like that.  Don't confuse display layout with actual data shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,2], [3,4]]], [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,2], [3,4]]]])
>>> a
array([[[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]],


       [[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]]])
```

Comment: yes, but i want them replicated into columns as well , a 2X2 matrix which has 2X2 matrices as elements

Comment: So you mean a 4D matrix ? I edited the answer, let me know if it's what you're looking for

Comment: yes, a 4D matrix , a 2X2 matrix the elements of which are 2X2 matrices

Comment: The `shape` is (2,2,2,2).

Comment: right that's what i was looking for , took me a while to realise